# Autocompletearrayinput TypeError: Polyglot.transformPhrase expects argument #1 to be string

Tags: react-admin

Hello stack overflow I was wondering if  its possible to pre-populate  with default values upon rendering. I'm also getting an error when using the  from react admin. Here's my how i'm using my .

```
return (
    <Edit {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput source="audience_name" />
        <ReferenceInput label="entity_ids" source="entity_ids" reference="posts">
          <EntityInput setEntityLabel={onChangeLabel} onSelectEntity={addEntity} entityNames={entityNames} />
        </ReferenceInput>
        <br />
        <AutocompleteArrayInput
          source="tags"
          shouldRenderSuggestions={(val) => {
            console.log(val);
            return val.trim().length > 0;
          }}
          choices={[
            { id: 'programming', name: 'Programming' },
            { id: 'lifestyle', name: 'Lifestyle' },
            { id: 'photography', name: 'Photography' },
          ]}
        />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the props `translateChoice={false}`, like:

```
<AutocompleteInput source="first_name" choices={choices} translateChoice={false}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try recreating the i18nProvider, like this:

```
import polyglotI18nProvider from "ra-i18n-polyglot"; // Install this package
import engMessages from "ra-language-english"; // Install this package

const App = () => {
    const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider((locale) => engMessages, "en", {
        allowMissing: true,
        onMissingKey: (key, _, __) => key,
    });

    return (
        <Admin
            ...
            i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
        >
    )
}
```